# Is there a way to avoid the "null" return?

Tags: java, return-value

I'm working on a method which draws a rectangle using asterisks. My method does return the desired rectangle, yet it obliges me to add a return statement with a "null" value. How can I get rid of this "null" value? Using "void" instead of "String" in the method did not work.

My code is the following:

```
public class Rectangle {
   
    int width;
    int height;
    
    public Rectangle() {
        this.width = 0;
        this.height = 0; 
    }

    public String draw() {
        for(int i = 1; i <= this.height; i++){
            for(int j = 1; j <= this.width; j++){
                System.out.print("* ");
            }
            System.out.print("\n");   
        }      
        return null;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return draw();
    }
}
```

By running this code:

```
public class Essay {
    public static void main(String[]args) {
        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(5, 3);

        System.out.println(rectangle.toString());
    }
}
```

the result is:

[image]

Comment: you do not have to return null, you can simply return an empty string : `return ""`

Comment: Don't print _in_ (anything called from) your `toString` function!

Comment: @Emad Ali: by returning an empty string "", I still have an empty line which is still undesirable. The method should only draw the rectangle without printing a "null" string or an empty line.

Comment: then i suggest following the other 2 examples from @Ryan Millares and @Davis Herring. having a draw function to return a String to be passed to `toString()` to return it again to your `System.out` is unneccesarly. make your `draw()` method void, remove the return and since you made it a public method, it can be used in your main:  `rectangle.draw();`

Comment: The method doesn't actually return anything!?

Comment: @EmadAli in addition to using `return ""` in your Draw() function, try changing your print statement in class Essay from `println()` to `print()`, like: `
Also try changing your final print statement from `println` to `print`

   ` System.out.print(rectangle.toString());` to avoid newline, see if that works

Comment: How did " Using "void" instead of "String" in the method did not work."  happened? Did you called the void method inside the `System.out.println()` statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, `draw` doesn't actually return anything (useful), instead you're just printing the stars directly to the output stream.

Instead, what you should (probably be) doing, is building a `String` within the `draw` method which can be returned to the caller, for example...

```
public String draw() {
    StringJoiner outter = new StringJoiner("\n");
    for (int i = 1; i <= this.height; i++) {
        StringJoiner inner = new StringJoiner(" ");
        for (int j = 1; j <= this.width; j++) {
            inner.add("*");
        }
        outter.add(inner.toString());
    }
    return outter.toString();
}
```

Now, I'm using `StringJoiner` for simplicity (and because I'm lazy and it's just an amazing class), but you could equally get away with using `StringBuilder`, but you'd need to inject the additional properties yourself.

Then calling `System.out.println(rectangle.toString());` would actually print the return result from the `draw` method

## Runnable example...

```
import java.util.StringJoiner;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(5, 3);

        System.out.println(rectangle.toString());
    }

    public class Rectangle {

        int width;
        int height;

        public Rectangle(int width, int height) {
            this.width = width;
            this.height = height;
        }

    public String draw() {
        StringJoiner outter = new StringJoiner("\n");
        for (int i = 1; i <= this.height; i++) {
            StringJoiner inner = new StringJoiner(" ");
            for (int j = 1; j <= this.width; j++) {
                inner.add("*");
            }
            outter.add(inner.toString());
        }
        return outter.toString();
    }

        public String toString() {
            return draw();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @ MadProgrammer: nice! It worked just fine. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 7):

`toString` implementations should return the string value that represents the object instead of printing it directly, as there's no guarantee that the caller of the method will want to print it. Imagine, for example, that you want to write the result of `toString` to a file -- how would you do it if it just printed to the console and returned nothing?

The best way to go about this is to modify your implementation of `toString` to build the asterisk rectangle as a string and return it without printing anything. But if you just want to solve this problem anyway, you can return an empty string instead of null.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution is to have your `Draw()` return empty string `return ""` to make sure the word "null" isn't printed.

```
public String draw() {
    for(int i = 1; i <= this.height; i++){
        for(int j = 1; j <= this.width; j++){
            System.out.print("* ");
        }
        System.out.print("\n");   
    }      
    return "";
}
```